# hadoop mapreduce - Retain specific entries after secondary sorting using composite key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, composite-key, secondary-sort

I have done a secondary sorting using composite key (hadoop mapreduce java). The sorted data looks like:

```
(asec) (desc) (asec)

id     num    price

1      10       9

1      10      10

1       8       7

2      10       9

2       8      12
```

**(id, num)** is the *composite key*.

The expected result is:

```
id     num    price

1      10       9

2      10       9
```

That is, for each id, get the largest num and lowest price (if there are some same largest nums).

How should I write the reduce method to finish this step?

Comment: You need to collect the entries for the same key in a temporary variables and then compare with the next values and output that result finally. It is not that hard. Another point to note is that largest num and lowest price may not occur in the same entry. E.g there could be entry where largest num occurs for that id but lowest price occurs with another num for the same id.

Comment: @user238607 So should I write a method or implement the temporary variable in the reduce method?

Comment: Yes you can use variables in reduce function. You can exhaust all the values from the iterable and select the values that satisfy your conditions and then finally out the desired result.

Comment: @user238607 In reduce, I can compare the price (which is the value), but how can I compare the num, which is part of the composite key? Sorry for this simple question, I am newbie to mapreduce..

Comment: You can define extra methods on the composite key which will return the num value. See here : https://tutorials.techmytalk.com/2014/11/14/mapreduce-composite-key-operation-part2/